# Is it possible to write custom SQL in OrmLite?

Tags: sql, persistence, ormlite

I have a class which I want to persist with [OrmLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ormlite/) and it stores most of its data in a HashMap. I want to map these fields to the table in Sqlite, leaving the ones absent in the map as `null`. Is it possible to override methods to save some record to the database with custom implementations using OrmLite?

Comment: Is this map supposed to be a collection of SQL rows in a table?  For example, if you have 100 things in the Map, would you have 100 rows in a SQL table?

Comment: @Gray, no. Say there are `column1`, `column2`, `column3` in the table. The `Map<String, Object` contains (e.g.) `column2` => 'foo', `column3` => 'bar'. Then the resulting row would be 1 => null, 2 => foo, 3 => bar.

Anyways, I've switched to Hibernate, so this question isn't relevant.

Comment: I'm the author of OrmLite and I'm just curious if there is missing functionality that I should consider adding.  So the idea is that the Map stores one row.  The String key is the column name and and the Object value is its associated data?  But you could use an object instead of a Map, right?  Call setColumn2("foo") and setColumn3("bar").  Isn't that a more Java way of doing it?

Comment: @Gray, perhaps that would be more javish, but I'd like to have customization ability. What really was a deal-breaker for me with OrmLite was that I can't have custom SQL queries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395398/is-it-possible-to-write-custom-sql-in-ormlite and no success with googling either).

Comment: Actually OrmLite does have custom SQL queries.  The Dao.queryForAllRaw(String query) returns a Map of <String,String> values.  It doesn't (yet) have custom updates or executes however.

Comment: Oh and I don't understand about the Googling.

Comment: So does hibernate allow you to persist a map of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think roddik has moved on but I thought I'd post an answer anyway as the author of OrmLite.

My general response is that it would be better to create an object to store the columns instead of a Map.  Although SQL is a row of string columns, the whole point of ORM is that we can deal with the rows as objects in Java instead of a Map of strings.

```
@DatabaseTable
public void RandomThing {
    @DatabaseField
    String column1;
    @DatabaseField
    String column2;
    @DatabaseField
    String column3;
    public void RandomThing(String column1, String column2, String column3) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Right now there is not a way to persist a Map of strings in ORMLite.